# Tips to improve mindfulness in daily life

Tags: theravada, personal-practice, mindfulness, meditation-practicalities, meditation-mindfulness

Does anyone know any new  beginners ways to improve mindfulness in
daily life?

Answer (score 3):

If you meditate regularly, the mindfulness in daily life will increase automatically. Perhaps a useful tip may be to have an activity - e.g. brushing your teeth (as suggested by a teacher in the tradition of Jon Kabat-Zinn) or showering, that you always try to do mindfully, that is, by just being aware. This is not a substitute for meditation, but it may be a way of assessing whether you are mindful at that time. SN Goenka says that it can be helpful if you are mindful when you fall asleep and just after you wake up, just observing sensations on your body and nothing else.